# Note taking app that can sync both android and Linux

Tags: software-rec, synchronization, android, notes

I've been looking high and low for an Evernote alternative for Linux. I know I can use Everpad or Evernote in WINE but they don't work natively.

Any note-taking app would be fine as long as it can sync my android and my linux.

Comment: see this http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/ (open source clone of Evernote) and also http://www.linuxalt.com/linux-alternatives-to/windows/evernote.html

Comment: Nevernote (NixNote) is working fine. Though the interface is less beautiful, it works!

Comment: what's the problem?  i use Evernote Web on Fedora 16 and on my Android and it all syncs up fine

Comment: If the paid attention when reading, I was looking for an app.

Comment: I actually use evernote as well in linux via their chrome extension, you should give it a go it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @foampile I'm on Evernote Web for the moment. Nothing beats it...yet

Comment: You could use [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) which is really effective for note taking and sync with [Unison](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34826).

Comment: Just keep your notes as .txt and use dropbox.  No fuss, no problems.

Comment: [NixNote2](https://github.com/baumgarr/nixnote2) is out now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a wiki like [Zim - a Desktop Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/) and save its files to a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) folder. For Android you can use [WikiMind note](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweetrain.wikimind.pro&hl=en) to work with the Zim Wiki. I'm sure there are other apps that can work with Zim's files since they're just text with wiki markup.

**EDIT #1**

Other options for Android if the $3 price for WikiMind is too steep.

- [WikiMind Lite](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/wikimind-lite)
- [ZimDroid](https://launchpad.net/zimdroid) (it's under development and not usable but something to keep an eye one)
- List of ["Wiki" apps on appbrains](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=wiki)
- [Epistle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kooklab.epistle) a Markdown editor

Comment: I will try it sometime. For now NixNote does the job.

Comment: WikiMind isn't a free alternative sadly.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned that there are probably others.

Comment: Thanks for the more information. I'm looking at TomDroid as well. Under development too.

Answer (score 3):

If you like plain text notes with markdown support I can also recommend [QOwnNotes](http://www.qownnotes.org) in combination with [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/).

There are software repositories for Ubuntu, openSUSE and Fedora, as well as packages for OS X and Windows.

And you can sync to mobile devices via the notes mobile apps.

Comment: Of course it also works with Nextcloud!

Answer (score 2):

There is an Evernote add-on for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

Google keep seems to be quite good:

https://drive.google.com/keep/

Answer (score 0):

Dropsync app is needed to synchronize the dropbox zimwiki notebook folder with the wikimind (lite or full) folder

Comment: I tried wikimind and the alikes and there is not a simple and direct way to sync notes. Unlike Evernote where I have a app itself and syncing is automatic. Right now I'm using Web Evernote for the moment

Answer (score 0):

[TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) is a document managing application that also support note writing, and it can run on both Linux and Android. It does not provide a synchronization feature natively, but you can combine it with DropBox, OwnCloud or SpiderOak to sync between your devices.